# How to know the scale of an extra dimension in units of length?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, universe, spacetime-dimensions, branes

I’m studying a model with an extra fifth dimension with
a scale factor $b(t)$ . The modified Friedmann-like equations are:

$$
\left[ {\left( {\frac{{\dot a}}{a}} \right)^2  + \left( {\frac{{\dot a}}{a}} \right)\left( {\frac{{\dot b}}{b}} \right)} \right] =Z  +H_0^2 \left( \frac{\Omega_{m0}}{{a^3}} +  \frac{\Omega_{r0}}{a^4} + \Omega_{\Lambda0} \right),$$

$$ 2\frac{{\ddot a}}{a} + \left( {\frac{{\dot a}}{a}} \right)^2  + \frac{{\ddot b}}{b} + 2\left( {\frac{{\dot a}}{a}} \right)\left( {\frac{{\dot b}}{b}} \right) = H_0^2 \Omega_{\Lambda0}-H_0^2   \frac{\Omega_{r0}}{3a^4}  - Z ,$$
$$\left[ {\frac{{\ddot a}}{a} + \left( {\frac{{\dot a}}{a}} \right)^2 } \right] = \bar{\Lambda}- Z.
$$

Where $a(t)$ is the scale factor of our 4-dimensional  observed universe, given :

- The current value of the Hubble parameter $H_0= 67150 ~m ~\text{Mpc}^{-1} \text{sec}^{-1} =0.0686751 ~\text{Gyr}^{-1}$
- The current values of the density parameters of the matter, energy, and radiation are: $\Omega_{m0}=0.31, \Omega_{\Lambda0}=0.69$ and $\Omega_{r0}= 1-\Omega_{\Lambda0}-\Omega_{m0}$

Z is an extra field, and $\bar{\Lambda}$ is the cosmological constant of the fifth dimension in units of $\text{Gry}^{-2}$.

Solving these equations numerically for a(t), b(t), and Z(t) gives this plot:

[image]

Where the black curve is b(t), the blue curve is a(t) of the model, and the red curve is the scale factor of $\Lambda$CDM model as plotted by this code: [Lambda-CDM’s scale factor](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/FLRW.functions.html)

My question: given the scale factor of the extra dimension b(t), how to get the scale or the size of this extra dimension in the units of length ?

Or is there any way to know further information about this fifth dimension, whether it’s compactified or infinite?

The metric is Robertson-Walker like:

$$
    ds^2  =  - dt^2  + a^2 \left( t \right) \left( {dr^2  + r^2 d\Omega ^2 } \right) + b^2 \left( t \right) dy^2. $$

Any help is appreciated!